# Can we do auth transaction in Telr as continuous authority transaction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, payment-gateway, telr

I am developing a service provider mobile app in react-native that uses **[Telr](https://telr.com/)** payment gateway for handling payments through cards. I followed **[Mobile API Integration Guide](https://telr.com/support/knowledge-base/mobile-api-integration-guide/)** and successfully integrated in my app . Till now I am able to make initial transaction with any of the transaction types provided by Telr in Mobile API. Initially I make **1.00 AED** transaction using transaction type of **sale** and transaction class of **paypage** . This is the minimum amount of transaction that we have to make when adding card in app. After successful initial transaction I get trans_ref(transaction reference) in response which I can use for making further transactions. All required details, such as card number and expiry date, will be retrieved from the transaction reference and I don't have to provide any card details again.

After this when I've to make another transaction using the same card I've to provide previous trans_ref in my transaction request and  use transaction type of **sale** with transaction class of **cont**. But I want to use transaction type of **auth** because of my apps business logic. Basically, I am developing a service provider app and when customer book or schedule any service using card, we need to hold the total bill amount until the service is finished and after successfully completion of service we have to transfer the actual amount from customer account to service providers account.

When I use transaction type of **auth** with transaction class of **cont** I get error message of **Invalid transaction type**, but when I use transaction type of **sale** with transaction class of **cont** everything works fine. I want to confirm that can we use transaction type of **auth** with **cont** transaction class or not?

Comment: Farook, Are you got solutions?

Comment: @Farook no, I contacted telr support team, they do not provide this functionality so I've moved to a new payment gateway called Checkout